# My variable says it's never used but it is?

Tags: c#

I've just started in C# and have been using only the console for the last week or so. I've now moved to using the Visual Studio IDE app builder and am having issues with a very basic program.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int chance = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    if (chance < 8)
    {
        bool hit = true;
    }
    else
    {
        bool hit = false;
    }

    if (hit == true)
    {
        mhealth -= damage;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(mhealth);
    }
```

It's telling me that 'hit' is never used but it is isn't it? The code doesn't work and I'm not sure what's going on, any help?

Comment: Define variable outside if-else

Comment: Read about "scope" in a c# tutorial.

Comment: As an aside, you could just use `bool hit = chance < 8`.

Comment: If you declare a `bool` **inside** the braces it is only visible inside them.

Comment: You can also simplify the code shown with a single line: `if (new Random().Next(1, 10) < 8) textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(mhealth -= damage);`

Comment: The code you posted shouldn't even compile, unless you've declared another `hit` variable somewhere. It is not clear at all from your question what you actually need help with, nor what the best fix would be. If you have a `hit` declared elsewhere and want it set, then probably if you just remove `bool` from the assignment statements (so you're not declaring a new variable) that would work fine. If you don't have `hit` declared elsewhere, the code shouldn't compile, and you shouldn't need `hit` at all; you could just write `if (chance < 8) { mhealth -= damage; ... }`

Comment: Thank you to everyone! I know understand scoping a lot more and found out what the issue was!

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare `bool hit` outside `if-else` statement. Please find below the code:

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int chance = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    bool hit;
    if (chance < 8)
    {
        hit = true;
    }
    else
    {
        hit = false;
    }

    if (hit == true)
    {
        mhealth -= damage;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(mhealth);
    }
```

OR

```
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int chance = rnd.Next(1, 10);
    bool hit = (chance < 8);
    if (hit)
    {
        mhealth -= damage;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(mhealth);
    }
```

Comment: Or simply `bool hit = chance < 8;`

Comment: @UnholySheep added that piece of code in the answer also :)

Comment: or simply `if (hit)`

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes thats nice catch :) Edited the code in answer above.

Comment: or simply `if (chance < 8)`. What's the point of the `hit` variable at all?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to scoping of your variable. You are declaring hit within if {} code block (and also in else block again. As such hit is not visible/accessible outside of the {} scope block. To fix this declare hit only once before you start your if block.

Review [scope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132(v=vs.71).aspx) concept in programming.